# Replace array value at SOME specific rows in matlab

Tags: matlab, indexing, find

I try to replace the array values at some specific row *(row number 1, 10, 12, 20, 39 etc, **not continuous**)* using the linear index from `find`. However I don't know how to proceed after this few lines of code:

```
[valmax, ~]=max(A); %Where A will consist of more than one MAX value
idxmax=find(A==valmax);
mclr=repmat([1 0 0],[10 1]); %Create the matrix of my value
mclr(idxmax,:)=[0 1 0]; %replace the value at idxmax index, this line won't work
```

Any idea how to fix this? Or there are other function instead of using `find`?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `ind2sub` to convert the linear indexes into row indexes:

```
A = randi(5,[10 3]); % random matrix
[valmax, ~] = max(A(:)); %Where A will consist of more than one MAX value
idxmax = find(A == valmax);
% convert linear index into row index
[rowmax,colmax] = ind2sub(size(A),idxmax);
rowmax = unique(rowmax); % get unique rows
mclr = repmat([1 0 0],[10 1]); %Create the matrix of my value
mclr(rowmax,:) = repmat([0 1 0],[numel(rowmax) 1]); %replace the value at idxmax index
```

however it's more efficient to directly get the rows containing max values using `any(X, 2)`:

```
rowmax = find(any(A == valmax,2));
```